# Typing when setting reactive property dynamically

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

When I try to set a reactive property by dynamically accessing the property, I get a typescript error,

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ settings : string; }'.`

The code is like this:

```
 const settings = reactive({
   name: 'hello'
 });

const setProperty = (property: string) => { 

  settings[property] = 'new value';           // <-- typescript error

}
```

I can get around it by typing "any" but that's not the correct solution:

```
(settings as any)[property] = 'new value';
```

So what would be a good way to type it?

Comment: well you can use `property: keyof typeof settings`, however you are assigning a boolean to string.

Comment: @wonderflame Okay that seems to work! (I edited and changed it to string just now).

Comment: please update the question body then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `keyof typeof settings` instead of `string` for the `property`.

```
const setProperty = (property: keyof typeof settings) => { 
  settings[property] = 'new value';
}
```